# Controlar excepciones %ISOPEN %NOFOUND de un cursor con un ciclo FOR

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo una función que me devuelve la suma de un pedido mediante un for, pero la una duda, donde controlo las expeciones %ISOPEN %NOFOUND, dentro del ciclo for o despues del BEGIN en el EXCEPTION?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CALCULAR_PEDIDO
    (P_CODIGOPEDIDO IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER
AS
    TOTAL_PEDIDO NUMBER := 0;
    CURSOR P1 IS (SELECT DE.CODIGOPEDIDO, DE.UNIDADESPEDIDAS, PR.PRECIOVENTA
                    FROM E_DETALLEPEDIDOS DE INNER JOIN E_PRODUCTOS PR
                        ON DE.CODIGOPRODUCTO = PR.CODIGOPRODUCTO
                    WHERE DE.CODIGOPEDIDO = 1);
BEGIN
    FOR I IN P1 LOOP
        TOTAL_PEDIDO := TOTAL_PEDIDO + (I.UNIDADESPEDIDAS * I.PRECIOVENTA);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN TOTAL_PEDIDO;
END CALCULAR_PEDIDO;

/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las excepciones siempre van dentro del bloque BEGIN..END. Normalmente se especifican al final del bloque. Por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE
   past_due EXCEPTION;
   acct_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
   ...
EXCEPTION
   WHEN past_due THEN  -- excepcion definida dentro de tu código PL/SQL
      ...
   WHEN OTHERS THEN    -- excepcion predefinida en el motor
      ...
END;
```

Existen además, excepciones predefinidas que usan los códigos que indican, como `TOO_MANY_ROWS`, `NO_DATA_FOUND`, [entre otras](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLS/exceptions.htm#TTPLS195). Revisa la documentación para que sepas qué excepciones predefinidas puedes usar. Esencialmente, cualquier instrucción dentro del bloque `BEGIN..END` que lance algún tipo de excepción, predefinida o personalizada, va a dirigir la ejecución del código hacia el bloque `EXCEPTION` y buscará si hay un `WHEN excepción_lanzada THEN`. Si no lo hay, terminará la ejecución y entregará la excepción como salida.

Cuando te refieres a %ISOPEN, %NOTFOUND y %ROWCOUNT, esas no son excepciones predefinidas sino atributos del cursor, entonces no corresponden al bloque EXCEPTION. Tampoco se usan solas, por eso tienen un `%` al comienzo, mientras que los nombres de excepciones predefinidas no lo tienen, como te acabo de mostrar.

Un ejemplo clásico de uso para los atributos del cursor sería:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR emp_cur IS SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY employee_id;
   emp_rec employees%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN emp_cur;
   LOOP   -- loop through the table and get each employee
      FETCH emp_cur INTO emp_rec;
      EXIT WHEN emp_cur%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line('Employee #' || emp_rec.employee_id ||
         ' is ' || emp_rec.last_name);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE emp_cur;
END;
/
```

Mira cómo se abre el cursor y se hace FETCH normal, añadiendo una condición de salida cuando ya no haya más registros para traer (el fetch es registro por registro). El uso es entonces `nombre_cursor%ATRIBUTO`. Espero que sea más claro ahora.

Puedes revisar [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems011.htm).

Comment: Perfecto, pero en ese bloque EXCEPTION como controlaría  concretamente estas %ISOPEN %NOFOUND, no veo nada en la documentación

Comment: @LuisQuesadaRomero edité la respuesta para tratar de explicar la confusión que tienes.